# Get specific index of JSON Nested objects in java Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, nested

How I can get only the "name" string of every object under "fields" Array, of main Array index at 0 & then next index using loop or with something super idea

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bank1",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "Email",
                "slug": "email",
                "type": "input"
            },
            {
                "name": "City",
                "slug": "city",
                "type": "input"
            },
            {
                "name": "Screenshot",
                "slug": "screenshot",
                "type": "file"
            },
            {
                "name": "Full Name",
                "slug": "full-name",
                "type": "input"
            }
        ],
        "status": "Active"
    },
    {
        "name": "Bank2",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "Email",
                "slug": "email",
                "type": "input"
            },
            {
                "name": "City",
                "slug": "city",
                "type": "input"
            },
            {
                "name": "Screenshot",
                "slug": "screenshot",
                "type": "file"
            },
            {
                "name": "Submitted Date",
                "slug": "submitted-date",
                "type": "calendar"
            }
        ],
        "status": "Active"
    }
]
```

**Output I want:**
Email
City
Screenshot
Full Name

Means in the output, I have got index 0, first object array data...

What I have done yet

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);


                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                               
                                String p_name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                                 ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

                                JSONArray ja = jsonObject.getJSONArray("fields");
                                int len = ja.length();

                                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                                    JSONObject json = ja.getJSONObject(j);
                                    arr.add(json.getString("name"));
                                }


}}catch block...
```

this gives me all indexes name data i want only specific index data
**My Current Output:**
Email
City
Screenshot
Full Name
Email
City
Screenshot
Submitted Date

Comment: Use Hash map for storing both index and its value _name_

Comment: how can you show me an example? @Piyush

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get specific index data then you should pass **if condition** in **for loop**.

**EX:** to get output of **index 0** like,

Email

City

Screenshot

Full Name

Your code would be like below.

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);


                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                          if(i==0){

                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                           
                            String p_name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                             ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray ja = jsonObject.getJSONArray("fields");
                            int len = ja.length();

                            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                                JSONObject json = ja.getJSONObject(j);
                                arr.add(json.getString("name"));
                            }

                           }
 }}catch block...
```

Comment: but there will be infinite index 0,1,2,3.... so how can i do for that?

Comment: but I think you said that you want only specific index data.(So, I mean your problem is when you add into list there you need to determine particular index)

Comment: So, for that you may need to create model class.

Comment: No I want only specific data on specific index do you have any solution pls help me

Comment: you want to get all data but on other side you want only specific index data when you need right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236377/discussion-between-vatsal-dholakiya-and-androwaqar).

Answer (score 0):

```
               int i=gotIndex;//here you can give your exact index that you want
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                           
                            String p_name = jsonObject.getString("name");

                             ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();

                            JSONArray ja = jsonObject.getJSONArray("fields");
                            int len = ja.length();

                            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                                JSONObject json = ja.getJSONObject(j);
                                arr.add(json.getString("name"));
                            }
```

here you used the loop you can use the json object out side the loop with using the index number i (jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i))

Comment: but i want next array data which means index 1 after 0 data thats why i used loop any solution? @AjayKS

Comment: what is your real problem?

Comment: see question I want specific index  "fields" array data, under that only name string of objects

Comment: see now you will understand i have updated my question @AjayKS

Comment: I think the code is correct, and your printing method or something is incorrect, the logic you mentioned is correct. the implementation method is incorrect.

Comment: yeah so pls help me do you have any solution for my logic

Comment: what you are just printing the p_name object that not what Im expecting

Comment: then what are you expecting

Comment: first read my question I want the specific index of "fields" array data and only name of that array objects and I had write the output above what i need